# 80s Cartoon with Robots that have Human partners unlocking abilties

Tags: story-identification, robots, cartoon, mecha

What I remember:

- early - mid 80s cartoon
- white(?) robots/mechs
- "Family" of robots
- one of the "kid" robots was oval in shape with long legs
- Family/Team of Humans were also on the planet, but separately
- Some initial mistrust between the humans/robots
- One of the human kids jumps in the cockpit of the kid robot and plugs in/pulls a visor down/interfaces
- this results in some new ability of the robot to show up
- Apparently the robots were built to be teamed up with humans to reach a bigger potential than either group could alone
- this results in the robots and humans teaming up to work together against external threats(???)

Comment: I vaguely remember this - one of the robots had dual Pentium processors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of *Robotix*.

- Aired: 1985
- White robots based on "Robotix" construction sets
- Narra was the four-legged dome robot
- The kid was the first to bond with the robots
- The humans were chased to the robots' planet
- The humans teamed up with a set of "good" robots and a set of "evil" robots.

Description on Wikipedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotix

Here it is on YouTube.

Comment: Why? What about Robotix matches the details in the question?

Comment: I have added some details.

Comment: Why not embed the actual youtube video? That's the usual practice here.

Comment: It didn't seem to work, but I will try it again. :)

Comment: Much better! SE doesn't like to embed https links from youtube for some reason. Just switch them to http, and they embed fine.

Comment: Who puts the future in your hands?