# Help identifying old 80s (early 90s?) show where robots needed human pilots

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Does anyone recall an old show with warring robot factions where it turned out that if they had human pilots their (previously dormant) weapons systems worked? I think this became apparent after some humans crashed onto their planet and the humans discovered cockpits inside the robots.

I know this sounds like the Transformers S4 rebirth arc, but I was pretty sure that the discovery was accidental unlike the deliberate bonding that happened in that show.

I watched it on VHS with English audio in the early 1990s. Can't remember whether it was a movie or series with an ongoing plot.

Comment: Hello Indy500 and welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to try to add more detail to your story-id question.

Comment: This could be the Targetmaster/Headmaster Transformers arcs.

Comment: Thanks @Xavon_Wrentaile. I initially thought that it was part of the Transformers headmasters storyline, but having just rewatched the S4 rebirth arc this seems similar but not quite what I remembered happening.

Comment: @Indy500 Which one?  There were both a US and a Japanese Headmaster series, and they were different.  Maybe you say both and mixed them in your mind?

Comment: what did the robots look like?

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [Robotix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotix)? From the first episode summary:

> Pursued by a battle cruiser, the starship of captain Exeter Galaxon crashes on the ruined planet of Skalorr and its occupants left for dead. However, the crew survives, only to immediately find themselves caught up in a battle between two factions of gigantic robot creatures - the Protectons and Terrakors - that emerge from the ground. While the Terrakors flee the scene, the Protectons befriend Galaxon and his crew, and help them rebuild their ship. During the repairs, Narra and Zarru discover that humans can interface with Robotix to enhance their abilities, while a renewed attack by the Terrakors forces Bront to put the new discovery to the test.

So you've got humans crash landing, warring robot factions, and the robots can have human pilots. And the series is from 1985, so it's possible for you to have seen it in the 90s.

The [whole series is on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zvRNKs9Z2M) - does this look familiar?

Comment: This sure seems like a match to me, based on the description

Comment: If so, this would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91403/80s-cartoon-with-robots-that-have-human-partners-unlocking-abilties/91409#91409 (trying to establish links for all of the times this has come up as a good answer)